# Dictionary: How to find Max of Elements

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a dictionary of...

```
result={'A - - -': ['ALLY'], '- - A -': ['DEAL'], '- - - A': ['BETA'], '- - - -': ['COOL',    'ELSE', 'FLEW', 'GOOD', 'HOPE', 'IBEX']}
```

How would I go about assigning a variable 'Answer' to the key with the most elements? I tried...

```
inverse=[(value,key) for key, value in result.items()]
Answer=max(inverse)
```

but that got me no where. Since the largest family is ['COOL', 'ELSE', 'FLEW', 'GOOD', 'HOPE', 'IBEX'] I would like to be able to assign '- - - -' to 'Answer'.

Answer (score 4):

[`max()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#max) takes a `key` keyword argument which allows you to give a sorting function:

```
>>> answer, _ = max(result.items(), key=lambda x: len(x[1]))
>>> answer
'- - - -'
```

This will be more efficient than constructing an extra list just to sort on.

Comment: @FrancisAvila That only works in 2.x, argument unpacking was removed in 3.x, so it's best avoided in new code.

Answer (score -1):

You are sorting by the lists themselves instead of their length:

```
inverse = [(len(value), key) for key, value in result.items()]
Answer = max(inverse)[1]
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import operator
dict(sorted(result.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:1])
```

There you have your maximum value, now just assign something to it?

Comment: -1, this just makes no sense. Making a dictionary from sorted values removes the sort you just did, as `dict`s have no order.

Comment: Dict can have order, if you choose to have so. Secondly you need it there or something at least in order to get 1 value out of the whole dict without knowing which value is the biggest. Since you can't do [:1] or [..anything..] on a dict without known values.

Comment: `dict` objects do not store order. Your new method fixes that bug by only having one item, but then the construction of the `dict` is pointless. Beyond that, your answer still gets the wrong result, even with your edit.